# Creating a RichFaces popup panel as a Facelets subview/composition not hidable

Tags: jsf, popup, richfaces, facelets, el

Popup panels in RichFaces are pretty ugly to work with to be honest. There are several calls to some JavaScripts involved which makes it not easy to derive something that works in general. Anyway, I was trying the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"            
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
                xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

  <h:commandLink>
    <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="#{buttonImageFileName}"  />
    <rich:tooltip value="#{buttonTooltipText}" direction="bottomRight" />
    <rich:componentControl target="#{popupId}" operation="show" />
  </h:commandLink>
  <rich:popupPanel modal="true"
                   height="#{popupHeight}"
                   resizeable="#{popupResizable}"
                   onmaskclick="#{componentCallToId}.hide(); return false;"
                   id="#{popupId}">
    <f:facet name="header">
      <h:outputText value="#{popupHeaderText}" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="controls">
      <h:outputLink value="#" onclick="#{componentCallToId}.hide(); return false;">
        <h:outputText value="X" />
      </h:outputLink>
    </f:facet>
    <p>#{popupSubject}</p>
    <p>
      <h:inputText value="#{inputTextBean[inputTextProperty]}" styleClass="full-width" id="#{inputTextId}" />
    </p>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto;">
      <h:commandButton value="OK"
                       action="#{acceptButtonBean[acceptButtonMethod](acceptButtonMethodArg)}"
                       onclick="#{componentCallToId}.hide(); return true;">
        <a4j:ajax execute="@this #{inputTextId}" render="@form" />
      </h:commandButton>
      <h:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{componentCallToId}.hide(); return false;" immediate="true" />
    </h:panelGrid>
  </rich:popupPanel>

</ui:composition>
```

This displays an image button which pops up a simple input dialog, which is **supposed** to be hidden by clicking outside the popup (onmaskclick="..."), by X'ing the popup in the top right corner (`<f:facet>` with `onclick="..."`), or by pressing the Cancel `<h:commandButton onclick="...">`. On OK the AJAX form is **supposed** to be submitted and the popup is hidden, too. But nothing happens (can't close):

[image]

The EL expression `#{componentCallToId}.hide(); return false;` is the "problem child" in the above. It is not working that way.

In its **original, non-Facelets** variant here (http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=popup&sample=modalPopup&skin=classic) the call to control the component looks like this:

```
<h:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('add-root-chapter-popup')}.hide(); return false;" immediate="true" />
```

I pass the following parameters to `<ui:include>`:

```
<ui:include src="/subviews/add-node-clink-input-popup.xhtml">
  <ui:param name="buttonImageFileName" value="add.png" />
  ...
  <ui:param name="popupId" value="add-root-chapter-popup" />
  <ui:param name="componentControlCallToId" value="rich:component('add-root-chapter-popup')" />
  ...
</ui:include>
```

Notice the long entry (the rest seems to be working - even the strange syntax for the bean + method + arg, but this is not the focus here).

**Q:**

Why isn't `<ui:param name="componentControlCallToId" value="rich:component('add-root-chapter-popup')" />` working? Currently nothing happens when clicking outside the popup, X'ing, or pressing OK or Cancel (popup staying).

Firebug only shows:

```
syntax error
.hide(); return false;
```

Looks like the expression is evaluated to null/empty string.

**What's wrong? Can it be fixed?** What are my alternatives?

---

PS: Note, that I've previously tried to use the "popupId" in the Facelets expression like

```
<h:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component('popupId')}.hide(); return false;" immediate="true" />
```

but this has the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omitting the single quotes did the trick:

```
<h:commandButton value="Cancel" onclick="#{rich:component(popupId)}.hide(); return false;" immediate="true" />
```

I thought they were part of JS, but they seem to be EL here.

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try this:-
onmaskclick="#{rich:component('cc.attrs.popupId')}.hide()"
If the quotes cause you any problem use     **&quot**;    instead of them.

I believe here you are trying to parse the id to the popup panel dynamically through your custom components exposed variables.
Where in you might be parsing the value for id as

popupId="xyz"
If this being the  situation the above solution would work just fine.